# Norm with exponential

Tags: functional-analysis

I can't find the paper where it was written, but I remember that in the proof of Picard theorem (existence and unicity of the solution in Cauchy problem), they used a norm that contain the function exponential, i.e. something as $$\|f\|=\sup_{t\in [a,b]} |e^{\lambda t}f(t)|,$$
but I don't remember what it was.

1) Someone could recall me this norm ?

2) Why using this norm instead the norm of supremum ? In what is it in interesting norm ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ obeys a Lipschitz condition $$||f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)||\leq K||y_1-y_2||$$ on the stripe $S=[a,b]\times\mathbb{R}^n$ that contains a point $(\xi,\eta)$. Then You can choose a number $\lambda>0$ such that $\frac{K}{\lambda}<1$. If You define the norm $$||u||_{\lambda}=\max\{||u(x)||e^{-\lambda|x-\xi|}:x\in[a,b]\}$$ on $C_0([a,b],\mathbb{R^n})$ and the operator $T$ on $C_0([a,b],\mathbb{R^n})$ by $$(Tu)(x)=\eta+\int_{\xi}^xf(t,u(t))dt$$ then this operator fulfills $$||Tu-Tv||_{\lambda}\leq\frac{K}{\lambda}||u-v||_{\lambda}.$$That means $T$ is a contraction with respect to $\textbf{this}$ norm and now You can use Banachs fixpoint theorem to show existence and uniqueness of the solution to the differential equation that You have in mind.